# Problema de programación orientada a objetos

Tags: python, poo

¿Me podrían ayudar con este programa que no he podido realizar? es en Python. Voy a adjuntar el problema y al lado lo que llevo programado, disculpen si quizás no esta bueno del todo. Cualquier aporte que me puedan hacer me ayudaría un montón, gracias de antemano.

El ejercicio que deseo realizar es el siguiente:

**Ejercicio Tienda de Libros**

Se quiere construir un aplicación para una tienda virtual de libros. La tienda tiene un catálogo o colección de libros que ofrece para la venta. Los libros tienen un ISBN que los identifica de manera única, un título y un precio con el que se venden. Cuando un cliente llega a  la tienda virtual a comprar libros, utiliza un carrito de compras. En el carrito de compras va adicionando los libros que quiere comprar. El cliente puede llevar más de un ejemplar de cada libro. Al revisar la cuenta, el cliente debe de poder ver el subtotal de cada libro según la cantidad de ejemplares que lleve de él, además del total de la compra, que es igual a la suma de los subtotales.

**Código:**

```
class tienda_libros:
    def __init__(self):
        self.carrito= carro_de_compras()
        self.catalogo= {0:libro(0, "Lluvia fina", 33000),
                        1:libro(1, "Amsterdam", 40000),
                        2:libro(2, "Seducción", 80000),
                        3:libro(3, "Obsesión", 60000),
                        4:libro(4, "Devoción", 100000),
                        5:libro(5, "Los renglones torcidos de Dios", 50000),
                        6:libro(6, "Plata quemada", 20000),
                        7:libro(7, "Intimidad", 40000),
                        8:libro(8, "Leonora", 56000),
                        9:libro(9, "Éramos unos niños", 17000)}

    def buscar_libro(self, isbn):
        for i in self.catalogo:
            if isbn == i:
                return self.catalogo.get(i)

    def adicionar_libro_al_carrito(self,isbn,cantidad):
        pass

class libro:
    def __init__(self,isbn, titulo, precio):
        self.titulo= titulo
        self.isbn= isbn
        self.precio= precio

class item_compra:
    def __init__(self,cantidad, libro):
        self.cantidad= cantidad
        self.libro=libro

    def cantidad_libros(self, cantidad):
        return self.cantidad

    def calcular_subtotal(self, cantidad, precio):
        pass


class carro_de_compras:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items_compra= []
        self.subtotal= 0

    def agregar_libro_a_carrito(self,isbn):
        pass
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que mires [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Es mejor que añadas tu código y no una imagen de el, ya que se dificulta poder trabajar sobre el mismo

Comment: coloca el enunciado de tu problema y tu código como texto, muchos somos cegatones

Comment: El código no debe pegarse como imágenes. Es difícil de leer e imposible de copiar (con coy&paste) para modificar. Mira aqui como formatearlo correctamente para una pregunta en este sitio --> https://bit.ly/SOesPASTE

Comment: Ya lo edite, pero no entiendo porque algunas partes me quedan como si fuera texto normal, pues como si no fuera codigo

Comment: Por favor lee el [tour] asi sabes como funcionamos. Entendemos que tenes que resolver un ejercico, ahora, cual es el problema? no vamos a resolver el ejercicio por vos (asi no funciona el sitio), pero si te podemos ayudar con algun problema en particular que tengas. Ademas, tene en cuenta que este sitio es gratis para todos, con lo cual tu urgencia puede no ser la urgencia de nadie. Una vez que hagas la pregunta concreta con un problema concreto, si alguien puede te va a contestar. Duplicar la pregunta no va a hacer que te contesten mas rapido.

Comment: Si necesitas agregar informacion, usa el boton [edit] y hace los cambios que necesites en tu pregunta

Comment: Por lo que veo en tu código solo has definido los atributos, métodos y clases, pero no has intentado nada realmente. Los métodos están vacíos. ://